# C# screen recorder reduce AVI video file size

Tags: c#, compression, screenshot, filesize

I'm currently trying to make a screen recorder in C#, and so far it works but the problem is that something as simple as a 20second video will take about 1GB of space. I have it setup so a timer continuously takes screenshots with this method:

```
void takeScreenshot()
        {
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    //Add screen to bitmap:
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }
                //Create and save screenshot:
                string name = path + "//screenshot-" + fileCount + ".jpeg";
                bitmap.Save(name, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                inputImageSequence.Add(name);
                fileCount++;

                //Dispose of bitmap:
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

And then it stores those pictures in a temporary folder in the D:// drive, and then when it's done it takes all the pictures and creates an AVI video out of them like this:

```
//Set bounds of video to screen size:
            Rectangle bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
            int width = bounds.Width;
            int height = bounds.Height;

            var framRate = 5;

            using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                //Create new video file:
                vFWriter.Open(outputPath+"//video.avi", width, height, framRate, VideoCodec.Raw);

                //Make each screenshot into a video frame:
                foreach (var imageLocation in inputImageSequence)
                {
                    Bitmap imageFrame = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation) as Bitmap;
                    vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(imageFrame);
                    imageFrame.Dispose();
                }
                vFWriter.Close();
            }
            //Delete the screenshots and temporary folder:
            DeletePath(path);
```

Any help on reducing the inefficiency of this is appreciated, I'm fairly new to this kind of programming.

Comment: If the code is otherwise working as expected, consider posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Guess I have to wait 40min for that lol

Comment: `VideoCodec.Raw` -- Uncompressed video is definitely going to be huge. Pick a different codec if you want it to use less space.